# How to preserve list indentation after RET in markdown-mode?

Tags: indentation, markdown, markdown-mode

When I'm editing a markdown-mode document with a list like this:

```
* foo
* bar
  * baz
```

and my cursor is at the very end of the `baz` line, and I press `RET` (which is bound to `markdown-enter-key`) then the `baz` line gets dedented so the file looks like this:

```
* foo
* bar
* baz
```

But what I would like is for the indentation to behave like most programming modes, i.e. keep `baz` where it was, and on the newline align my cursor with the `baz` bullet point so I can start typing another bullet point at that level, e.g.

```
* foo
* bar
  * baz
  *
```

How can I configure my emacs to do this?

Comment: Try `M-RET` ('markdown-insert-list-item').

Comment: @xuchunyang That's the answer, why not make it one :)

Comment: That works, thanks, but I'd like to make `RET` do that (or that without the `*`).

Comment: Personally I am satisfied with using one extra specific key `M-RET` to indent list items, instead of trying to make `RET` to do different things base on context (but that context is probably not enough and will produces ambiguity and instability, for example, when to start and end a list is unexpected, which means you always have to do it manually).  But I do know some markdown editors (e.g., https://github.com/uranusjr/macdown) do what you requested, so I guess you can try to implement it yourself and/or talk to the markdown-mode author.

Answer (score 1):

I made a new command for your request, the idea is:

- when the point is outside a list, just insert a newline as usual
- when the point is inside a list

  - if the current list is empty, delete it and insert a newline
  - otherwise, insert a new list item

```lisp
(defun markdown-enter-key-dwim ()
  (interactive)
  (require 'subr-x)                     ; Needs Emacs 24.4
  (if-let ((bounds (markdown-cur-list-item-bounds))
           (beg (car bounds)) (end (cadr bounds))
           (text (buffer-substring beg end)))
      (if (and (>= (length text) 2)
               (string-blank-p
                (substring text 2)))
          (progn
            ;; Delete current blank list
            (kill-region beg end)
            ;; Insert RET
            (markdown-enter-key))
        ;; Create a new list
        (call-interactively #'markdown-insert-list-item))
    ;; Not within a list environment
    (markdown-enter-key)))

(require 'markdown-mode)
(define-key markdown-mode-map2 (kbd "RET") #'markdown-enter-key-dwim)
```

Notes, `markdown-enter-key-dwim` is not well-tested (probably too aggressive) and needs future work. The built-in <kbd>M-RET</kbd> (`markdown-insert-list-item`) is still handy enough for me, maybe you can just use it as well.